# Package org.apache.harmony missing?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want to write an extend of the class *SSLCertificateSocketFactory*. First I search for the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java/) of the class and found it.
After all I want to overwrite the method `private SSLSocketFactory makeSocketFactory(TrustManager[] trustManagers)`.

A look into the method shows up that I need the class *SSLContextImpl*. It seems to be in the package *org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl*.
But there isn't any package *org.apache.harmony.**.

I am confused because the class *SSLCertificateSocketFactory* needs it.
If the package is not included in the SDK and I have to get it from www.apache.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the android source code? If yes then look for these classes somewhere in the /dalvik/system or security directory, since right now I didn't remember the actual path. If you don't have the source code download it from [Android Source code](http://source.android.com/source/index.html)

Comment: In the sources you can find the class in the folder `org/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse`. But why do I have to manually add files?

Comment: Is there no other possibility? I have to add more than 68 files to get it working and the libs are delivered with Froyo.

Comment: Since there is no jar available that contains these classes as per my information, so you have. to manually add them